# Using the officer package; is it possible to apply the "Shrink text on overflow" functionality from a placeholder in your ppt template?

Tags: r, officer

I use officer to generate ppt presentations from a range of data sources and generally use conditional statements to control the font size on my slides based on number of characters in a string or rows in a table. However, this can be tedious and is not a perfect solution.

Is it possible to use the inherent placeholder text box option to shrink text to fit in the same way vertical alignment or margins can be applied?

[image: 1]